# How to check if two database are identical, and how much is the difference?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, consistency

I have exported a database and then imported it into a new database. Then I can see that there is a difference in size, which I came to learn that it is due the space reuse issue for deleted entries which is not exported.

So, now two databases should be identical in terms of active (non deleted) entries. But, how can I check that? [system: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin, webmin, etc.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several free and paid tools to do this, both on data and on table structure etc.
most can even generate scripts to sync database a with b.
search google for database compare tool (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of checking if two database schemas are the same is to generate script for each database and compare/diff if the scripts are the same.